# ActiveXObject.Save() method gives permission denied error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
    function getfun(a)
    {
      var xmlObj = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument");

            var sXml  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>" ;
                  sXml += "<soap:Envelope "
                  sXml += "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" " ;
                  sXml += "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" " ;
                  sXml += "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" ;
                  sXml += "<soap:Body>" ;
                  sXml += "<Add xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" ;
                  sXml = sXml + "<a>" + a.value  + "</a>" ;

                  sXml += "</Add></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"

   // Try to parse the XML string into DOM object 
            xmlObj.loadXML(sXml) ;

            var xmlHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP") ;
            xmlHTTP.Open ( "Post", "http://localhost/MyWebVirtual/MyWebService.asmx", false) ;
            xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/Add") ;
            xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8" ) ;
            xmlHTTP.Send(xmlObj.xml) ;

            var xmlResponse = xmlHTTP.responseXML ;
            answer.innerText = xmlResponse.selectSingleNode("soap:Envelope/soap:Body/AddResponse/AddResult").text ;

            var xmlObj2 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlObj2.resolveExternals = true;
            xmlObj2.preserveWhiteSpace = true;
            xmlObj2.validateOnParse = false;
            xmlObj2.async = false;
            xmlObj2.loadXML(xmlResponse.selectSingleNode("soap:Envelope/soap:Body/AddResponse/AddResult").text);
            xmlObj2.save("C:\\Users1.xml");

 }
```

I am getting an error while saving xmlObj2 to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Did you set the permissions for the Folder or Directory.?

Folder or Directory -> Right click -> Properties-> Security -> Group Names -> Allow

please check that.

Set user permission for all user Group Names and Check Again.

hope this may helpful.

Comment: First which Error your getting while saving..? please explain your problem clearly.

Comment: Please Visit this: meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234.since it seems you have not yet discovered how to accept answers